# prettyCheckable stopping jquery validation from working in checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-validate

I desperately need help. I have a form. And I am trying to validate this with jQuery. I am using jQUery validation and jquery prettyCheckable (from [here](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/) ). Now it validates everything. However, at the places I am using custom checkbox using pretty checkable (custom9-11), it does not validate.

To call prettycheckable I am calling

```
$().ready(function () {
  $('input.myClass').prettyCheckable();
});
```

When I take that call out, it validates.

Comment: Try passing a option `ignore: ''` to the validator.... `$('#submitDetails').validate({ ignore: '', rules:...})`

Comment: it is because the validator ignores hidden fields.... in your case the actual checkboxes are hidden

Comment: Thanks it worked kinda. You can see in the live link. However, when I click the checkbox , the custom error message does not get hidden away ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because since you are using a masked input elements(actual input element is hidden here) the validation framework ignores those elements.

You can override this behavior using the `ignore` option

Try

```
$('#submitDetails').validate({ ignore: '', rules:...})
```

Comment: Thanks. However when I click back the checkbox the error message does not disseaper...

Comment: it is because the validation plugin listens to the click event for validation and the styling plugin is firing it... it is firing only the change event

Comment: Add a handler like `$('#custom9').on('change', function(){ $(this).valid() })`

Comment: Hi It is not 100% working. Please follow the following steps to reproduce the issue 1) Click on link staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/plush_form.do 2) Click on submit button at the bottom 3) Click on the red error message after the checkbox (do not click the checkbox or the label of the checkbox). The error message disseapears . Now if you click the checkbox, the error message reappears whereas it should not. ???